# Pattern Finding and Replacement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am currently in need to find a sql statement to do some pattern recognition and replacement. Below is my problem description:

I need a sql statement or something that would replace numbers in a string with the following conditions. Consider the test string: "$125.00 Cost, 33% Percentage"
1. Replace all numbers followed by dollar sign with the string {cost}
2. Replace all numbers before percentage sign with the string {percentage}

Expected output: ${cost} Cost, {coinsurance}% Percentage.

Example String Input 2: $25 Cost  ---> Output: ${cost} Cost

String Input 3: 33% Percentage ---> Output: {percentage}% Percentage.

String input 4: $25 ----> Output: ${cost}

String input 5: 33% ----> output: {percentage}%

I came up with the below sql statement to replace these separately:

```
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(MAX) = '33% percentage'
SELECT STUFF(@Text,PATINDEX('%$[0-9]%',@Text)+1,PATINDEX('%cost%',@Text)-2,'{cost} ')
,PATINDEX('%[0-9][%]%',@Text)- 1, STUFF(@Text,PATINDEX('%[0-9][%]%',@Text)- 1,2,' {percentage}')
```

The above SQL, seems to be working in all cases related to percentages text and also for example text 1.

I need a single statement that would replace the texts correctly. The above statement works replacing individually. Also, the statement related to replacing with "{cost}" doesn't work with Input 4.

Can someone help me with the regular expression and stuff statements to improvise on this.Please reach out to me if I can provide further details.

Comment: _"The above SQL, seems to be working in all cases"_, Are you looking for [improvment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I need a single statement that would replace the texts correctly. The above statement works replacing individually.
Also, the statement related to replacing with "{cost}" doesn't work with Input 4.

Comment: TSQL does not support regular expressions.

Comment: @TabAlleman: I'm sure we could search using regular expression patterns using PATINDEX function.

Comment: Patterns, yes, but not regular expressions.   They are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant, but this is where my thinking takes me.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(150))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('$125.00 Cost, 33% Percentage'),
('$25 Cost'),
('33% Percentage'),
('$25'),
('33%')

Select A.*
      ,NewString = case when charindex('${cost}',S)>0 and charindex('{percentage}%',S)>0 then replace(S,'{percentage}','{coinsurance}') else S end
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select S = Stuff((Select ' ' +case when right(RetVal,1)='%' then '{percentage}%' 
                                                   when left(RetVal,1)='$' then '${cost}' 
                                                   else RetVal end
                  From (
                        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.SomeCol,' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                       ) B1
                  Order by RetSeq
                  For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol                        NewString
$125.00 Cost, 33% Percentage    ${cost} Cost, {coinsurance}% Percentage
$25 Cost                        ${cost} Cost
33% Percentage                 {percentage}% Percentage
$25                         ${cost}
33%                            {percentage}%
```

> **Edit - Remove Trailing CRLFc**

Change

```
replace(A.SomeCol,' ','§§Split§§')
```

To

```
replace(replace(replace(A.SomeCol,char(10),''),char(13),''),' ','§§Split§§')
```

Comment: Thank you. The sql works perfectly for all cases. I am also getting "&#x0D; " extra character in some records as the data already has trailig carriage returns in the text and the XML PATH is generating these characters. I know I have to trim or remove these special characters before processing. Can I do it inline in this same query? I tried LTRIM and RTRIM in various places on the above query, but it doesn't seem to reflect.

Comment: @KashyapMNVL Ltrim/Rtrim will not remove the trailing CRLFs see update in a moment